# How can sshfs be made more reliable?

Tags: ssh, sshfs

I use sshfs to connect the filesystem on my computer to that of my web host.

I find that after a few hours of being connected, the sshfs becomes unmounted and synchronization no longer happens. Is there any way to make sshfs more reliable, perhaps so it tries to reconnect?

Comment: Does the issue occur after periods of (sshfs) inactivity? Or does it also occur if you’re actively using the connection?

Comment: It generally occurs after periods of inactivity, but I have seen it happen during activity also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use -o reconnect

I have been using it for a while now with that option and it reconnects even when the remote server comes back from offline state to online. Ubuntu 14.04 both machines.